# Query SQL Server count value of count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query as below:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         h2.hacker_id, COUNT(c2.challenge_id) AS co
     FROM 
         hackers h2 
     INNER JOIN 
         challenges c2 ON h2.hacker_id = c2.hacker_id
     GROUP BY 
         h2.hacker_id
     HAVING 
         COUNT(c2.challenge_id) = 1)
```

But, my query can not execute well and I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Msg 102 comes from SQL Server, so I edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a table name for the FROM (  ) table eg add a simple T after the closing )

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT h2.hacker_id, count(c2.challenge_id) as co
    FROM hackers h2 INNER JOIN challenges c2 ON h2.hacker_id = c2.hacker_id
    GROUP BY h2.hacker_id
    HAVING count(c2.challenge_id) = 1
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an alias for the subquery in either SQL Server or MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT h2.hacker_id, count(c2.challenge_id) as co
      FROM hackers h2 INNER JOIN 
           challenges c2
           ON h2.hacker_id = c2.hacker_id
      GROUP BY h2.hacker_id
      HAVING count(c2.challenge_id) = 1
     ) x;
```

Assuming that your `hacker_id`s are all well defined, you do not need the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT c2.hacker_id, count(c2.challenge_id) as co
      FROM challenges c2
      GROUP BY c2.hacker_id
      HAVING count(c2.challenge_id) = 1
     ) x;
```

If you have a unique id in `challenges`, you can also phrase this as:

```
select count(*)
from challenges c
where not exists (select 1
                  from challenges c2
                  where c2.hacker_id = c.hacker_id and c2.challenge_id <> c.challenge_id
                 );
```

With an index on `challenges(hacker_id, challenge_id)`, this should have the best performance (once again, regardless of database).